# AWK - Return minimum value in input based on common feature

Tags: awk, gawk

I have the following input:

```
...
MSG1 10ms
MSG2 20ms
MSG3 25ms
MSG1 5ms
MSG3 2ms
MSG2 1ms
...
```

I am after an output like the following:

```
MSG1
Min: 5ms

MSG2
Min: 1ms

MSG3
Min: 2ms
```

The code I have so far, which has the layout that I am after is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
        print "Testing"
} #End of BEGIN
{ #Start of MID
        key = $1 #Message Extracted 10 Total
        min = 100
} #End of MID
END {
                for (MSG in MSG_TYPE) {
                        print MSG
                        print "MIN: "min
                        print "\n"
                }
} #End of END
```

But I am unable to pull the minimum value from the input data. I know how to logically get the data but actually coding it is another matter. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk '{m=$2+0; a[$1]=a[$1]?(m<a[$1]?m:a[$1]):m} END{for (v in a) {printf "%s\nMin: %sms\n\n", v,a[v]}}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `m=$2+0` - Which makes `5ms` to `5` integer part.
- `a[$1]?(m<a[$1]?m:a[$1]):m` - At very first `a[$1]` will have empty value for the index of `$1`, so setting `m` as initial value. For next time, `a[$1]` will have value, then doing the checking against `m<a[$1]`.

Comment: Thanks for this but I really would like it to be part of the above script as this is a part of it that has been requested.

Comment: Added explanation.

Comment: resolved it. I had to put the initial loop outside of the `END` block and just print `a[v]`

Answer (score 1):

## Input file:

```
cat data
MSG1 10ms
MSG2 20ms
MSG3 25ms
MSG1 5ms
MSG3 2ms
MSG2 1ms
```

## command:

```
    #List all the files with minimum values
    #Print only first occurrence of those files.
    #Print values below to file name
    #Print keyword "Min:" 


  sort -g -k2 data | awk '\!seen[$1]++' | sort | xargs -n 1 | sed 's/^[0-9]/  min: &/g'
MSG1
  min: 5ms
MSG2
  min: 1ms
MSG3
  min: 2ms
```

Comment: Could you explain how the `awk` section works please?

Comment: @GlennLynam : print the line if it hasn't been seen yet, then in any case increment the seen counter

Comment: Ahh ok then, Thanks for that. If I wanted to implement that into the script in the example how would I go about it?

Comment: In above solution, just replace "data" with your file. It should work. or it you are getting data from other command insted of file then run like this : 

INPUT_SOURCE |sort -g -k2 | awk '\!seen[$1]++' | sort | xargs -n 1 | sed 's/^[0-9]/  min: &/g'